# display ArrayList values in JSP page

Tags: jsp, struts, jsp-tags, struts-1, struts-tags

i have scenario like this..

```
ArrayList<String> list1=new ArrayList<String>();
     list1.add("str1");
     list1.add("str2");
     list1.add("str3");

ArrayList<String> list2=new ArrayList<String>();
     list1.add("str1");
     list1.add("str2");
     list1.add("str3");
     .
     .// like this i have 10 lists
     .
    list10.


ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> AllLists=new  ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    AllLists.add(list1);
    AllLists.add(list2);
      .
      .
    AllLists.add(list10);

in Struts Action Class 
   request.setAttribute("allLists",AllLists);
```

how to display this Arraylist values in JSP page using

`<logic:iterator> and <bean:write>` tags  give me some idea..

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Do yourself a favor, and learn the JSTL. It's been 10 years the struts documentation recommends using the JSTL.

Answer (score 0):

```
<logic:notEmpty name="allLists" indexId="idx">
  <logic:iterate id="value" name="allLists">
    <bean:write name="value"/> or ${value} with index ${idx}.
  </logic:iterate>
</logic:notEmpty>
```